# Why fprintf doesn't write directly into the file unless fflush() is used?

Tags: c, linux, file-io, flush, buffering

I have written a daemon that writes a value in a file. What I have observed is that when I keep writing on a file, there is nothing visible in the file. in other hand, If I use `fflush()` method then the characters are visible in the file. Why fflush() makes a difference?

Answer (score 5):

By default, stdio is fully buffered, unless it's writing to a terminal, in which case it's line-buffered, or stderr, which is not buffered at all.

You can disable buffering with the `setbuf()` function.

```
setbuf(fp, NULL);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because it's *buffered*. That means all writes are stored in a buffer in memory until the buffer is flushed. For `printf` and friends it's when it has either a newline, or you explicitly call `fflush`, or of course if the buffer becomes full.

Comment: What is that buffer size? At the time of overflow, it should write on the file right?

Comment: @SHREYASJOSHI That is implementation defined, so it can differ between platforms and libraries. It can also depend on the type of file, for example `stdout` may have one buffer size, a disk file another.

Answer (score 0):

`fprintf` is an IO routine provided by the libc, it use caching mechanism by default, before doing a real write into files.

Characters are normally accumulated and transmitted asynchronously to the file in a block, so the cache must exceed the libc(stdio) internal buffer size (BUFSIZE, #defined in stdio.h) or when a fflush() has occurred.

If you want to minimize the caching i suggest you to use O_DIRECT or O_SYNC flags for your `open` call, but there is some restrictions: you must ensure alignment of your buffers and other stuffs. Read the `O_DIRECT` [section](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open) of `man 2 open` .

you may also read [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Stream-Buffering.html) for further informations on how to control libc buffering.