# fprintf() is not working in ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu, file-io

I'm trying to learn File I/O concepts in C programming language. I'm using **GNU / Linux ( Ubuntu 16.04 LTS )** and my IDE is **eclipse 3.8**. when I try to write in a file through `fprintf()` method, it doesn't create any files or if the file is even created, it doesn't write in it. I tried to fix the problem by using `fflush()` or `setbuf(file_pointer, NULL)` methods as is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20267244/why-fprintf-doesnt-write-directly-into-the-file-unless-fflush-is-used) but still no change. I guess I'm writing the address of the file in a wrong way.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    FILE *file_pointer;
    file_pointer=fopen("~/.textsfiless/test.txt","w+");
    setbuf(file_pointer,NULL);
    fprintf(file_pointer,"Testing...\n");
    fclose(file_pointer);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Can someone explain what's wrong here?

Comment: `setbuf(file_pointer,NULL);` must be done after file `fopen`...

Comment: why don;t you check for the success of `fopen()`?

Comment: Check the `fopen` returned value, it can fails in case of wrong file path.

Comment: @LPs I did changed order of the lines as you said but it still doesn't work

Comment: Because that was one of the problem. Check `if (file_pointer != NULL)` before to use it.

Comment: @ErfanKhalaji try checking the return value of fopen

Comment: @LPs
I did check the code again by debugging it. It says the "iosetbuffer.c: No such file or directory.". If it's so and the path I used is wrong, then what could be the right format of file path when I'm programming while GNU/Linux is my OS.

Comment: `"~/.textsfiless/test.txt"` --> `"/home/ _UserName_ /.textsfiless/test.txt"`

Comment: @LPs I've tried it before. it doesn't fix the problem

Comment: So you probably haven't got rights on that dir. launching your app with `sudo`

Comment: BTW, you should question first your code instead of claiming that a standard library function does not behave as documented; bugs in your code are much more probable than bugs in `fprintf` which is *very likely* to work !

Answer (score 4):

On Linux, the `~` in `~/.textsfiless/test.txt` is not expanded by the C library `fopen`... When you use `~` on the command line, it is expanded by your [*shell*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell) (but *not* by the program using it, started by the shell doing some [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)...) into your [home directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory); the expansion is called [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29). Read [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html). You are very unlikely to have a directory named `~`.

You should read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

So you should check if `fopen` failed (it is very likely that it did fail). If you want to get a file in the home directory, you'll better use [getenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html) with `"HOME"` (or perhaps [getpwuid(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwuid.3.html) & [getuid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getuid.2.html)...). See [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html)

Perhaps a better code might be:

```
 char*homedir = getenv("HOME");
 if (!homedir) { perror("getenv HOME"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
 char pathbuf[512]; /// or perhaps PATH_MAX instead of 512
 snprintf(pathbuf, sizeof(pathbuf), 
          "%s/.textsfiless/test.txt", homedir);
 FILE *file_pointer = fopen(pathbuf, "r");
 if (!file_pointer) { perror(pathbuf); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

and so on.

Notice that you should check against failures most [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) (& [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)) functions. The [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) function is useful to report errors to the user on `stderr`.

<sup>(pedantically, we should even test that [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) returns a length below `sizeof(pathbuf)` or use and test against failure [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) instead; I leave that test as an exercise to the reader)</sup>

More generally, **read the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c)** of every external function that you are using.

Beware of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (your code is probably having some, e.g. `fprintf` to a `NULL` stream). Compile your code with all warnings & debug info (so `gcc -Wall -g`) and use the `gdb` debugger. Read [What every C programmer should know about undefined behavior.](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)

BTW, look into [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) and try it on your original (faulty) program. You'll learn a lot about the [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) used in it.

Comment: I want to delete the question but I cant.
please delete your answer.

Comment: I see no reason to delete my answer. It has been upvoted more than once, so it is not that bad ....

Answer (score 3):

Most likely your call to `fopen()` fails. You don't have any checking in your program to ensure `fopen` even worked. It may not have, and this could be due to a variety of things, like you spelling the path wrong, wrong file or process permissions, etc.

To see what really happened, you should check fopen's return value:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    FILE *file_pointer;
    file_pointer=fopen("~/.textsfiless/test.txt","w+");
    if (file_pointer == NULL) {
        printf("Opening the file failed.");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    setbuf(file_pointer,NULL);
    fprintf(file_pointer,"Testing...\n");
    fclose(file_pointer);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Edit: Since your comment, you getting the path wrong is most certainly what happened. If you're executing your program from the current directory, and your file is in a folder called "textfiless" in your current directory and your file is called "test.txt", then you'd call `fopen` like this:

```
file_pointer=fopen("/textsfiless/test.txt","w+");
```

Comment: As I guess and I mentioned in the question , it seems that the directory I used, does not exist. but I always use the directories like this and I have no problems. I can't figure out what's the file directory look like here.

Comment: @ErfanKhalaji I added a piece about that to my answer.

Comment: I did what you've written as your Edit but still no change.
Can you please vote up my question? I really don't find anything wrong with the question but the people are down voting.

Comment: @ErfanKhalaji: what is wrong with your question is that you did not read the documentation and did not search enough on the web. So people are right in downvoting it here.

Comment: I want to delete the question but I cant. please delete your answer.

Comment: @ErfanKhalaji Please do not ask other users to delete their answers. If you wish to delete your question, please flag it for moderator attention and explain why you wish to delete it.