# Delayed output in openMP for loop when using -O3

Tags: c, openmp

I have written this code that performs some computationally demanding tasks inside a for loop which I paralellize using openMP.  So I can keep track of where the program is I have it output to a file its current position in the loop.  This works beautifully when I compile it with no flags but when I use -O3 the entire output is delayed until the loop has completed.  Is there a way to prevent this from happening and ensure the program follows the order of the tasks I give it?  Here is an example code:

```
FILE *out;    
int progress = 0, i;
out = fopen("output.txt","w");

#pragma omp parallel for
    for(i=0; i<132; i++){
        progress++
        fprintf(out,"%d/132\n",progress);
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why fprintf doesn't write directly into the file unless fflush() is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20267244/why-fprintf-doesnt-write-directly-into-the-file-unless-fflush-is-used)

Comment: @Zulan I'm not sure whether the cause is actually the same here, since compiler flags seem to deterministically change the behaviour. @ FPerras could you show us the assembly outputs you get with and without the -O3 flag?

Comment: So... optimization prevents some implicit but never guaranteed flush? Go ahead and `fflush`....